# How to inflate another xml on clicking a button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, layout-inflater

I have one `Activity` in that there are no `Button`s but I have coded it in such a way that another `Activity` comes, now in this second `Activity` there are three `Button`s, on which when I click all inflating different respective activities. 
In this second `Activity` there I have added one more `Button`, on clicking this 4th `Button` I don't want another `Activity` to come in foreground instead i just want another layout to be inflated(I don't wanna change the `Activity`)
In that layout(which i need to inflate) I have a `ListView` which has a list of certain sites, when this layout is inflated the list of sites should be shown and as i click on there sites its should take me to that webpage.

**PROBLEM 1:** 
How to inflate just the `xml` on click of the 4th `Button` without changing the `Activity`.

**PROBLEM 2:**
When the `xml` is inflated and if I click on `BackButton` the `Activity` containing all the 4 `Button`s should be displayed.

Here is the code that I'm using to inflate another `xml`:

```
fourthButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        callingMore();
    }
});
private void callingMore() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_site_list_xml, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.site_list));
}
```

BUT this code gives a force close and no `xml` is being inflated and if I use `setContentView( R.layout.web_site_list_xml)` inside  `callingMore()` method
the `xml` is inflated but that `xml` doesn't show anything and then if I hit `BackButton`, the `Activity` that has all 4 `Button`s isn't shown.

Comment: Add your LogCat stacktrace so we can see what the ForceClose error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this code..hope helps to you..

**1.layout_existed.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/existedlayout"
    >
   <Button  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Clicck to inflate view"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2.layout_toinfliate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/mytext"
  android:text="You inflated me..i added to u r layout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

**3.LayoutInflateDemo.java**

```
  public class LayoutInflateDemo extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout layoutToAdd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_existed);
        layoutToAdd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.existedlayout);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                        .from(getApplicationContext());
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_toinfliate, null);
                layoutToAdd.addView(view);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in problem 1 ,you asked without changing the activity to inflate just the xml.if yo done that..problem 2 do not rise..

Comment: Thanks a lot sir its working but the older layout still exists i want the older layout to get to the background and this new layout that i inflated should be the only layout on which i can work... like clicking on the website links and all... kindly help

Comment: in this case what u have show its actually showing both the xml at a time but i want only one xml(layout_toinfliate.xml) on my UI and the older xml(layout_existed.xml) should not be shown.... is this possible?

Comment: what ever view(i.e,listview, textview..etc..)we have method like.. setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);setVisibility(View.GONE);use in appropriate place...ex: tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score -1):

Try using v.findViewByID()..

Pass View v to callingMore()

Comment: sorry sir,but i am not able to understand i am a little new to android kindly elaborate.